# Handling Shake Events in Android (1.5+?)

Tags: android, accelerometer, shake

Pretty new to Android development here... Is there an example out there of a working app with source that does something when you shake the phone? Is this doable in a background app? Done quite a bit of googling and can't find any good examples; only tutorials with little context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check these samples?

http://snipplr.com/view/14890/handling-shake-events-on-android-15/

http://www.clingmarks.com/?p=25